# Another dash/plotly dilemma

Tags: python, plot, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard

I hate to keep posting about dash\plotly but I cant understand what is going wrong here. I have copied and pasted from the plotly site the code in order to display a pie chart with a drop down menu. When I create the dashboard there is a dropdown menu that shows all the categories but there is no pie chart to be seen. Please help me to understand what is going wrong. Code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.express as px

# This dataframe has 244 lines, but 4 distinct values for `day`
url="https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBM-DS0321EN-SkillsNetwork/datasets/spacex_launch_dash.csv"
spacex_df=pd.read_csv(url)


spacex_df.rename(columns={'Launch Site':'Site'}, inplace=True)

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.P("site-dropdown:"),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='Site', 
        value='Site', 
        options=[{'value': x, 'label': x} 
                 for x in ['CCAFS LC-40', 'CCAFS SLC-40', 'KSC LC-39A', 'VAFB SLC-4E']],
        clearable=False
    ),
   
    dcc.Graph(id="pie-chart"),
])

@app.callback(
    Output("pie-chart", "figure"), 
    [Input("Launch Site", "value")])
def generate_chart(Site, values):
    fig = px.pie(spacex_df, values='Site', names='Site')
    return fig

app.run_server()
```

Comment: I took a look at your DataFrame and I am bit confused about what you want to display in your pie chart. The `'Site'` column are all strings so it doesn't make sense to pass the parameter `values='Site'` to `px.pie`. if I am not mistaken, the only column that contains values is `Payload Mass (kg)`. Also when you select a particular `Site` from your dropdown menu and subset your DataFrame by that site, then what are the different sectors of your pie chart supposed to be?

Comment: It is meant to show the total success and failures of each launch site. So the column 'class' which should have a 0 for success and a 1 for failure. However, I had not done that bit yet as was mainly focused on why there wasnt a pie chart showing at all. Do you reckon it has something to do with what the different sectors might be?

Comment: there's a few problems with your code: your `generate_chart` function should have one input instead of two, and you're calling `px.pie` with arguments for columns that aren't consistent with the column types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main issues with your code were that your `generate_chart` function had two arguments, but the `@app.callback` decorator had only one input argument, and that for the `values` argument in px.pie, you need to pass a column name whose values can be summed together. One issue with using px.pie in this case is that if you sum the values in the 'class' column, the 0s for success will always sum to 0.

Since you explained in your comment that what you really want to display in your pie chart is the count of successes and failures (which are 0s and 1s in the `'class'` column), I thought it would be easiest to sum up the number of 0s and 1s for the particular `'Site'`, and pass the arguments `labels=['success','failure']` and `values=[success_count, failure_count]` to `go.Pie`.

```
import pandas as pd
import dash
from dash import html, dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

# This dataframe has 244 lines, but 4 distinct values for `day`
url="https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBM-DS0321EN-SkillsNetwork/datasets/spacex_launch_dash.csv"
spacex_df=pd.read_csv(url)


spacex_df.rename(columns={'Launch Site':'Site'}, inplace=True)

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.P("site-dropdown:"),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='Site', 
        value='Site', 
        options=[{'value': x, 'label': x} 
                 for x in ['CCAFS LC-40', 'CCAFS SLC-40', 'KSC LC-39A', 'VAFB SLC-4E']],
        clearable=False
    ),
   
    dcc.Graph(id="pie-chart"),
])

@app.callback(
    Output("pie-chart", "figure"), 
    [Input("Site", "value")])
def generate_chart(value):
    pie_data = spacex_df[spacex_df['Site'] == value]
    success_count = sum(pie_data['class'] == 0)
    failure_count = sum(pie_data['class'] == 1)
    fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=['success','failure'], values=[success_count, failure_count])])
    fig.update_layout(title=f"Site: {value}")
    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

[image]